# A question about Kotlin Function Type cast

Tags: kotlin

Code fragment in Kotlin

```
  public actual fun <R, T> (suspend R.() -> T).createCoroutineUnintercepted(
    receiver: R,
    completion: Continuation<T>
): Continuation<Unit> {
    val probeCompletion = probeCoroutineCreated(completion)
    return if (this is BaseContinuationImpl)
        create(receiver, probeCompletion)
    else {
        createCoroutineFromSuspendFunction(probeCompletion) {
            (this as Function2<R, Continuation<T>, Any?>).invoke(receiver, it)
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to know is How `(suspend R.() -> T)` AKA `Function Type` can be recognized
as `BaseContinuationImpl` which is a `Classify Type` even to cast as `Function2'.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no separate function types and class types. Function types are just types that can be executed with specific arguments and specific return type. They are interchangeable with `Function0`, `Function1`, etc. interfaces and they contain a single `invoke()` function.

We can implement a function type by our class:

```kotlin
class MyClass : (suspend () -> Unit) {
    override suspend fun invoke() {}
}
```

Now, let's get this code:

```kotlin
val lambda: (suspend () -> Unit) = {}
```

After disassembling we see that our lambda is compiled to:

```
final class FooKt$foo$lambda$1 extends kotlin/coroutines/jvm/internal/SuspendLambda implements kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1 {
    ...
    public final invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    ...
}
```

It extends `SuspendLambda` which is a subtype of `BaseContinuationImpl`. It also implements `Function1` and contains `invoke` function which makes it a function type.

Comment: Hi! Nice answer, thank you for clearance. Although I have one more question, maybe you know: `BaseContinuationImpl` has `fun create(completion: Continuation<*>)`, which is called in the snippet OP provided. However, I cannot find any meaningful implementation of this method, only throwing of `UnsupportedOperationException`. Have you found where does the real implementation of this method reside?

Comment: @aleien Continuations are not implemented in the stdlib. If we create a suspendable function/lambda, internally it creates an implementation of the `Continuation`. There you can find a real code for `create()`, `invokeSuspend()`, etc.

Comment: Aha, thank you. So, is it code generated? How can can I access this implemented real code?

Comment: @aleien you need to disassemble or decompile the resulting bytecode of your own project.